# How to fix No ":" found in value with Django core signing

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, axios, next.js13

I have a django rest framework api where a i create a token using the django.core.signing module. The signing and unsigning of object works fine when using an API Clinet (E.g) Postman. But when i try to connect with my Next Js frontend using axios it get.

> No ":" found in value for the token eyJlbWFpbCI6InJhbW9ucmFzaDJAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiZmlyc3RfbmFtZSI6IlJhc2hlZWQiLCJsYXN0X25hbWUiOiJSYW1vbiIsInBhc3N3b3JkIjoiTmluaW9sYTEyIiwiYWN0aXZhdGlvbl9jb2RlIjoiNzk3ODY5In0%3A1rBvFl%3Ato5l_EAmsHy76eJt0sHDcO_eqlk0k4fho78czQeNVx4. But the acutal token is eyJlbWFpbCI6InJhbW9ucmFzaDJAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiZmlyc3RfbmFtZSI6IlJhc2hlZWQiLCJsYXN0X25hbWUiOiJSYW1vbiIsInBhc3N3b3JkIjoiTmluaW9sYTEyIiwiYWN0aXZhdGlvbl9jb2RlIjoiNzk3ODY5In0:1rBvFl:to5l_EAmsHy76eJt0sHDcO_eqlk0k4fho78czQeNVx4

This is the API Code

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    activation_token = request.data.get("activation_token")
    activation_code = request.data.get("activation_code")
    print(activation_token)
    try:
        data = signer.unsign_object(
            activation_token, max_age=timedelta(minutes=10))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return Response({"message": "OTP has expired! Try registering again."}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    if data["activation_code"] == activation_code:
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            email=data["email"], password=data["password"], first_name=data["first_name"], last_name=data["last_name"])
        serializer = UserSerializer(user, many=False)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response({"message": "Invalid OTP"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

And The Axios Code

```
const response = await axios.post(
    `${BASEURL}auth/users/activate/`,
    JSON.stringify({
      activation_code: values.otp,
      activation_token: token,
    }),
    {
      headers: {
        Accept: "*/*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was anytime i put the token in the url it encode characters such as spaces,colon,comma etc.The solution is to decode the URI component back to it original form.

```
activation_token: decodeURIComponent(token),
```